# Using an iframe in jquery.simplemodal, the iframe reload when the popup is closed

Tags: jquery, iframe, simplemodal

```
var pt_popup_options = {};

function pt_popup_iframe(sURL, sOkFunction)
{
    pt_popup_okfunction = sOkFunction;
    $("#pt_msgBox").css('width', '700px');
    $("#pt_msgBox").css('heigth', '500px');
    $("#pt_msgBox > p").html('<iframe style="width: 696px; height: 496px;" src="' + sURL + '"></iframe>');
    $("#pt_msgBox").modal(pt_popup_options);
}
```

When the popup is closed via a close button or the "x" top right of the popup, the iframe reloads and make a request to the server. It is not supposed to do that. Any idea to prevent that? I'm on Chrome and jQuery 1.4.2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Easiest way to fix it is to set the `persist` option.

`$("#pt_msgBox").modal({persist:true});`

As of simplemodal-1.3.5

> persist: (Boolean:false) Persist the data across modal calls? Only
>   used for existing DOM elements. If true, the data will be maintained
>   across modal calls, if false, the data will be reverted to its
>   original state.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you're using jQueryUI's dialog, I wrote an extension a while ago that handles the various iFrame issues within a dialog...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work with:

```
$("#pt_msgBox > p").html('<iframe style="width: 696px; height: 496px;"></iframe>');
$("#pt_msgBox").modal(pt_popup_options);
$('#pt_msgBox').find('iframe').attr('src', sURL);
```